# ABAP SELECT database hints, correct syntax

Tags: grammar, abap

ABAP SELECT statements allow to give database hints. They start with the key word %_HINTS.  Now I wonder about the correct syntax of SELECT statements holding hints: which are all places hints can appear? I've checked the ABAP Keyword Documentation but they seem to be not mentioned.

Could you point me to some document that descrbes how database hints fit in the ABAP grammar?

More info about my question: We build a tool (in Java) that automatically transforms ABAP code to different ABAP code.  Applied on SELECT statements, it might add or remove clauses. Consequently, the position of hints might change as result of a transformation.  So, my question is *where* hints are allowed, not how correct hints look like.

Comment: Hmmm, interesting. Since when SELECT statements in OpenSQL allow hints?

Comment: I think they do. See here https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saponsqlserver/2011/08/31/how-to-integrate-sql-server-specific-hints-in-abap/

Comment: Well from this article I can see that SAP provided a rather vast [note](https://service.sap.com/sap/support/notes/129385) on how to do that. Have you considered reading it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The official documentation is in [note 129385](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/129385/E) (but unfortunately not accessible without an account).

Comment: Thanks. It took a while to get me the credentials. It says:
"You specify hints in the %_HINTS clause as the last clause of an Open SQL statement SELECT, DELETE, UPDATE or a subquery. You cannot specify hints in work area statements or statements other than SELECT, DELETE, or UPDATE."

Answer (score 0):

Two Examples for DB6 database , because the note does not contain any:

1. use nested loop join instead of hash join between VBAP and VBEP

`%_HINTS DB6 '<NLJOIN><IXSCAN TABLE=''VBAP'' />' DB6 '<IXSCAN TABLE=''VBEP'' /></NLJOIN>'`

2. use a custom index ZI0 for VBEP

`%_HINTS DB6 '<IXSCAN TABLE=''VBEP'' INDEX=''"VBEP~ZI0"'' />'`

EDIT: Hints are the last statement in a select block.

`SELECT *
INTO TABLE lt_table
FROM dbtable
WHERE x = 1
%HINTS "first hint 
%HINTS "second hint
. "<<< end of select statement`

Answer (score 0):

`... %_HINTS <DB type> 'one or more hints'` is described in the [ABAP documentation](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_753_index_htm/7.53/en-US/index.htm?file=abenosql_db_hints.htm) :

`<DB type>` represents the type of database to which the hint applies:

- ORACLE
- HDB
- ADABAS
- MSSQLNT
- DB6
- DB2
- etc.

There are two categories of hints (you may mix them in the same string):

- Open SQL hints
- Database hints

The Open SQL hints are interpreted by the SAP database interface at runtime and have a syntax between ampersands (some of them are described in the note [48230 - Parameters for the SELECT ... FOR ALL ENTRIES statement](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/48230/E)), so their syntax is known (but you have to read the SAP notes):

- &SUBSTITUTE LITERALS&
- &prefer_in_itab_opt 1&
- etc.

The Database hints are all the other hints which are not between ampersands. They are directly sent to the concerned database, which interprets them. If some hints are not valid, they are ignored by the databases. A short overview is provided in the note [129385 - Database hints in Open SQL](https://launchpad.support.sap.com/#/notes/129385/E), but you'll have to read the official documentation of your database system to have up-to-date information.

Note that the hints may be provided for several databases, but at runtime only the one of the current SAP database (if any) is used:

```
SELECT ... %_HINTS ORACLE  'INDEX...' 
                   HDB     'INDEX...'
                   MSSQLNT 'INDEX...'.
```

Hints are allowed for `SELECT`, `UPDATE` and `DELETE`, since at least ABAP version 4.5.

Hints may be checked by the compiler, as far as possible, in the strict mode.

Answer (score 0):

the hints depend on system. All places hints cannot appear but you can get it in System -> Status. On the right bottom of popup you could see DB System ###.

Often there are a DB6 and you can use something like this:

```
  select  a~opbel
          b~xblnr
          b~betrw
          b~kursf
          a~waers
          a~awkey
   from dfkkmko as a
    inner join  dfkkmop as b
    on a~opbel eq b~opbel
    into table lt_dfkkmko_p
   WHERE a~awkey IN lr_awkey
   AND   a~awtyp EQ 'VBRK'.
    bypassing buffer
    where a~awtyp eq 'VBRK'
and   a~awkey in lr_awkey
    %_hints db6 '&prefer_join 0&'.
```

Answer (score -1):

Just don't use it. If someday you migrate to HANA, this HINTs will break your code and you'll have to remove it one by one. I've try this hints before and does not increase performance significantly.

But if you still want to use it, these are DB specific, here are the syntax for Oracle

http://saptechnical.com/Tips/ABAP/SecondaryIndexes.htm

Comment: I'm not writing hints, I have to deal with existing ones. See my changed question

Comment: It takes only a parameter change to let HANA ignore all hints not meant for it.

Comment: What is HANA parameter to ignore sql hints written for other DB ?